# Why did I get the pundit badge?

Tags: support

I've just been awarded the Pundit badge, for making 10 comments with score of 5 or more. All very nice, but I'm curious to know which comments were well received.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/unix/query/483986/pundit-comments?UserId=100397) to find most of them; unfortunately the data isn't live, it was last updated yesterday.

Comment: I'd completely forgotten about the Data Explorer. Thank you for the useful reminder